# How to resolve typescript error for laravel mix's alias

Tags: reactjs, laravel, typescript, laravel-mix

I using react, I want to use absolute path when import component.

so I customized webpack.mix.js like below code.

That's worked well in browser.

But VScode show error.

```
 Could not find a declaration file for module
```

[image]

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix
    .ts('resources/js/app.tsx', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')

mix
    .webpackConfig({
        resolve: {
            extensions: [".js", ".jsx", ".tsx"],
            alias: {
                '@parts': path.resolve(__dirname, 'resources/js/components/parts'),
                '@pages': path.resolve(__dirname, 'resources/js/components/pages')
            }
        }
    });

if (mix.inProduction()) {
    mix.version()
}
```

Comment: Try adding them in [paths](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping) in your tsconfig as well